# Sort an object of array based on DATE as string

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to sort a JSON object based on date, i have month and year separately as well as date with both month and year but it is in form of string. I tried different approach but since it is as string, sometime it doesn't get sorted in correct way.

```
  const mockData = [
    {country: "CAN", startYear: 2015, startMonth: 2, endYear: 2030, startDate: 'FEB 2015'},
    {country:"IND", startYear: 2010, startMonth: 5, endYear: 2028, startDate: 'MAY 2010'},
    {country: "JPN", startYear: 2020, startMonth: 8, endYear: 2024, startDate: 'AUG 2020'},
    {country: "BRA", startYear: 2015, startMonth: 12, endYear: 2023, startDate: 'DEC 2015'}
  ];
```

So i need to sort this based on startDate

Desired Output :

```
[
{country:"IND", startYear: 2010, startMonth: 5, endYear: 2028, startDate: 'MAY 2010'},
{country: "CAN", startYear: 2015, startMonth: 2, endYear: 2030, startDate: 'FEB 2015'},
{country: "BRA", startYear: 2015, startMonth: 12, endYear: 2023, startDate: 'DEC 2015'},
{country: "JPN", startYear: 2020, startMonth: 8, endYear: 2024, startDate: 'AUG 2020'},
]
```

Comment: You don't explain what you have tried. Look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: "I need to sort a JSON object based on date". You need to sort a string? I don't see a string there and I am unclear how you wish to sort this string. Do characters in strings have dates? How do we know what the date of a character is in a string? What is the desired output (what do you want your string to look like)?

Comment: you need sort based in the three properties: startYear,startMonth and endYear. Tip, you can also create a new property in the way YYYYMMYYYY and sort by this one (be carefully, the month must has allways two digits),

Comment: @gforce301 , I need to sort on the basis of startDate, it is in string, also, i need it sorted , means the first upcoming year and month should come first, also i have updated the desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort by any key(s) of your objects, you just have to build the [sorting method](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/sort) yourself:

```
mockData.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.startYear < b.startYear || (a.startYear == b.startYear && a.startMonth < b.startMonth) || (a.startYear == b.startYear && a.startMonth == b.startMonth && a.endYear < b.endYear)) return -1;
    else if (a.startYear == b.startYear && a.startMonth == b.startMonth && a.endYear == b.endYear) return 0;
    else return 1;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you should convert startDate to string like '2010 08' (AUG 2010)

so code can be something like

```
const convertDate = str => {
  let [month, year] = str.split(' ')
  month = { JAN: '01', FEB: '02' ... DEC: '12' } [month]
  return year + ' ' + month
}

arr.sort((a, b) => convertDate(a.startDate) < convertDate(b.startDate) ? -1 : 1 )
```

or just use numeric fields

```
arr.sort((a, b) => a.startYear - b.startYear || a.startMonth -b.startMonth )
```